# wpf microsoft surface app -- touch won't trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch, touch-event

I'm building out my first touch application on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 device, in Visual Studio 2010 with the Surface SDK 2.0, and I'm having trouble with touch events. Click events are firing just fine, but none of the touch, previewtouch, or manipulation events are firing.

I can't find any question posted online regarding such a simple issue with touch. In surface app code examples, I can't figure out what I'm doing differently. Any ideas?

Thanks

XAML:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="SurfaceProject.SurfaceWindow1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
Title="SurfaceProject"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:SurfaceApplication1"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"           
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
xmlns:Microsoft_Surface_Presentation_Generic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic;assembly=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic" 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
xmlns:tve="clr-namespace:SurfaceProject"                              
d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="2000" WindowState="Maximized"

>
```

```
    <s:SurfaceButton 
        x:Name="SurfaceButtonTest" 
        Content="SurfaceButtonTest" 
        Grid.Column="4" 
        Margin="0" 
        Grid.Row="5" 
        TouchDown="SurfaceButtonTest_TouchDown" 
        Click="SurfaceButtonTest_Click" />
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;
  using Microsoft.Surface;
  using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation;
  using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls;
  using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Input;
```

//

```
    private void SurfaceButtonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SurfaceButtonTest.Content = "Click Received";
        //test
    }
    private void SurfaceButtonTest_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        SurfaceButtonTest.Content = "Touch Received";
        //test
    }
```