# touch event of surface 2.0 apps doesn't work in windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch, touchscreen, surface

i want to create new touch app for window desktop and i used surface 2.0 SDK for that, but my app doesn't get touch events in ScatterView or any control in my app.
i have multi-touch all-in-one PC and my touch screen work good on windows and other C# or WPF application.

thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35100507/1136211

Comment: elahiii man ghorboonet beshammmm :D